# Showing two times woocommerce cart notification with Design error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new in stack overflow community .I am facing issue with Beeketing (Recent Sales Popup app) Plugin Woocommerce .I have install Theme [Shopkeeper](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/shopkeeper-ecommerce-wp-theme-for-woocommerce/full_screen_preview/9553045) . Everything is working fine . when i install [Beeketing Woocommerce plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/beeketing-for-woocommerce/) after this when i click on Add to cart button, cart notification (XX Has been Added To your Cart) show two times with design error. after uninstall plugin everything run smooth. I inspect this issue using chrome Network `XHR` [Here is Image result of XHR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZZH2.png).I notice some request trigger after click on add to cart button .You can see error on my website using following [Link](http://www.womenfashion.pk) and here is video link , i make video related this issue [video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7KZOcOGeoI). Thanks and best regards

Comment: did you try with uncheck the add to cart ajax checkbox in woocomerce settings?

Comment: hi George . i do not want to make add to cart on load window , i like ajax features. how can i solve this issue.thanks

Comment: just disable the ajax option and check

Comment: ok, i will try it

Comment: still same issue  George

Comment: seems issue with card fragmentation div. are you using any plugin for cart icon at the header menu?

Comment: but try to understand  , when i remove plugin or deactivate , everything run smooth . only one time cart notification show. thanks